# Change the bar item name in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a test excel file like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':list('abcdefg'),
                   'age':[10,20,5,23,58,4,6]})

print (df)
  name  age
0    a   10
1    b   20
2    c    5
3    d   23
4    e   58
5    f    4
6    g    6
```

I use `Pandas` and `matplotlib` to read and plot it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

excel_file = 'test.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=0)
df.plot(kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

the result shows:
[image]

it use index number as item name, how can I change it to the name, which stored in column `name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify columns for `x` and `y` values in [`plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df.plot(x='name', y='age', kind="bar")
```

Or create `Series` first by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and select  `age` column:

```
df.set_index('name')['age'].plot(kind="bar")
#if multiple columns
#df.set_index('name').plot(kind="bar")
```